# Informatica 'Missing a required connection for session' Issue

Tags: informatica

I am new to Informatica. I have a workflow(developed by someone else) which worked fine in TST and UAT, on migrating to PROD it is erroring out with the following error msg:

```
Validating S_M_CTXS_******(version1)
SQ_CS_POS is missing a required connection for session S_M_CTXS_******
SQ_CS_POS_REPORT is missing a required connection for session S_M_CTXS_******
SQ_CS_POS1 is missing a required connection for session S_M_CTXS_******
Finish Validation
```

The values SQ_CS_POS,SQ_CS_POS_REPORT ,SQ_CS_POS1 are source values.

What does this error actually mean, what and where should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have hardcoded connections. In your session, on `Mapping` tab there's a `Sources` node. Check if all sources have valid connection chosen. Especially verify the `SQ_CS_POS`, `SQ_CS_POS_REPORT` and `SQ_CS_POS1`.

You can also review all the connections on the `Connections` node (`Mapping` tab as well).